# Proof check - The kernel of the stalk is the stalk of the kernel

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Given a morphism of sheaves $\alpha:F\rightarrow G$ of abelian groups over a topological space, I want to show that for any $x\in X$ holds $\ker(\alpha_x)=(\ker(\alpha))_x$.

Consider for any $x\in U\subseteq X$ open
$$\ker(\alpha(U))\stackrel{\iota(U)}{\rightarrow}F(U)\stackrel{\alpha(U)}{\rightarrow}G(U)$$
inducing
$$\ker(\alpha)_x\stackrel{\iota_x}{\rightarrow}F_x\stackrel{\alpha_x}{\rightarrow}G_x$$
since evidently $\alpha_x\iota_x=0$, $\ker(\alpha)_x$ is contained inside $\ker(\alpha_x)$ (or better there's an arrow by the universal property blabla).

Viceversa, take $s_x\in\ker(\alpha_x)$: then $s_x=(s)_x$ for some $s\in U$ open neighbourhood of $x$, and $\alpha_x(s_x)=(\alpha(U)(s))_x=0$: this means that there is an open neighbourhood $V\subseteq U$ of $x$ such that $0=(\alpha(U)(s))_{|V}=\alpha(V)(s_{|V})$: but this means exactly that $s_{|V}\in\ker(\alpha(V))$ and thus $s_x=(s_{|V})_x\in\ker(\alpha)_x$.

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: Here's the abstract nonsense proof: stalks are filtered colimits so they commute with finite limits.

Comment: @DerekElkins Do you know where is a proof that filtered colimits commute with finite limits?

Comment: @HeroKenzan It's in Borceux's Handbook of Categorical Algebra allegedly and on [p. 212 of Categories for the Working Mathematician](https://books.google.com/books?id=6KPSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA212&dq=categories+for+the+working+mathematician+%22filtered+colimits%22+commute&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPyNXe36fTAhUDLmMKHQbYD4IQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=categories%20for%20the%20working%20mathematician%20%22filtered%20colimits%22%20commute&f=false). Note this *doesn't* hold for all categories as mentioned on [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit). It holds for algebraic categories over **Set**, though.